# Too many open files using IntentService

Tags: android, file, intentservice

I am using an IntentService to periodically do a task. After every call of this service there will be three additional open files left.

On adb console this command shows all open files for a PID (process id):

```
lsof | busybox grep PID | busybox wc -l
```

Activity:

```
public class FileLeakActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        handler.post(mStartService);
    }

    private Runnable mStartService = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent svc = new Intent(FileLeakActivity.this, FileLeakService.class);
            FileLeakActivity.this.startService(svc);
            handler.postDelayed(mStartService, 1000);
        }
    };
}
```

Service:

```
public class FileLeakService extends IntentService {
    private final static String TAG = FileLeakService.class.getSimpleName();

    public FileLeakService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.android.fileleak"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <service android:name="FileLeakService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".FileLeakActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you found a resolution for this problem? 
I used intents to communicate between different services of my app - periodically, and after some time it dies.

Comment: I did not find any solution yet. Used Android version was 2.3.6

Comment: I have finally -kind of- solved it. Changed the whole stuff to use BroadcastRecievers, which need some kind of live-cycle-checking, and very dirty making them static, but it works well yet (48h runtime tests with about 10 intents/sec working ;) )